# Can I add or embed google analytics behavior flow report to my website?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api-php-client, behavior

I want to add google analytics **Behavior Flow** reports(embedded or from api) to my website. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

No you can not take the Google Analytics dashboard and display it on another website. The best option is to use the [Embedded API](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/).